# android application using java

Tags: java, android

morning dear freinds, i'm new in android and i have a problem with my button,when i click on it the program get closed with the message 09-14 12:39:30.197 10756-10756/com.mugenziisrael.Bus_booking E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mugenziisrael.Bus_booking/com.delaroystudios.bus_seat_booking_system.Sign_in}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class Button
```

Please anyone who know may help me to solve this issue, this is the main class.

```
package com.delaroystudios.bus_seat_booking_system;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main_activity_login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_login);
        Button login;
        Button sign;

        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.log);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         sign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signIn);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.roles_selection,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ "Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.RED);//TO change the color of spinner items
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){

            }
        });

        sign.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Sign_in.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
        login.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DetailsLogin.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );

    }
    }
```

the xml file is :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.delaroystudios.bus_seat_booking_system.Main_activity_login"
android:background="@drawable/bus1"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/contact"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            />
       <!--a verifier -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu1"
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        >
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/Login2"
      android:textSize="28sp"
android:textColor="#9b59b6"
      />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditLog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login"
            android:textColorHint="#9b59b6"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu2"
        android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Pass"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/your_password"
            android:id="@+id/Edit_menu2"
            android:textColorHint="#9b59b6"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/role"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/T_role"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/role"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"

    />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/men1"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/role"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/log"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            android:textColorHint="#9b59b6"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            />
       <Button
              android:id="@+id/signIn"
              android:layout_width="150dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            android:textColorHint="#9b59b6"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly code in line 71?

Comment: Please show signIn activity file layout.

Comment: thanks , let give you signIn activity

Comment: Show the Sign_in java code and the xml layout that this class inflates

Comment: please edit your question title so it is not so general, and describes your problem. It is obvious that you are doing `android application using java` because you've set `java`  `android` tags to your question.

Comment: Hint: nesting layouts is **bad for performances**. Please get rid of all those useless LinearLayouts. I know it's **easier to use them**, but you'll get **better performances by not using them**.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(//class activity where are you now ,give activity name where you want to go);
startActivity(intent);
```

Same for second button

Comment: I don't think so. This is a problem about inflating layout. Not how to start an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting 4 Character color code instead of 4 Character use 3 or 6 check all EditText

```
      <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/your_password"
        android:id="@+id/Edit_menu2"
        android:textColorHint="#9b59b6"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
       Button sign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signIn);
        sign.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this,Sign_in.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

First Check your manifest file and make sure your activity is been registered in manifest file.

Secondly,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main_activity_login.this,Sign_in.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Same for the next button.

Answer (score 0):

Your are not setting your on-click event correctly change your xml code for two button to this,

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/men1"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/role"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/log"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:onClick="buttonLoginClick"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            android:textColorHint="#9b59b6"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            />
       <Button
              android:id="@+id/signIn"
              android:layout_width="150dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:onClick="buttonSignInClick"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:textColor="#9b59b6"
            android:textColorHint="#9b59b6"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

now inside your Activity, Write

```
public void buttonLoginClick(View v){
// code for button one click

}


public void buttonSignInClick(View v){

//code for button 2 click
}
```

Hope you get my point